# Automated backup script for MOSS 2007 and WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I'm looking for example of scripts people are using to automate the backup of MOSS 2007 and WSS 3.0. Would be great to have built in support for various types and schedule of backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeplex.com/spbackup) is a powershell solution - it is pretty flexible and can backup everything you need to restore your site, or just individual site collections.

Answer (score 2):

We have a very small setup and run a full backup nightly.

One batch script that looks like this:

```
cd \
cd "Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN"
# you may hit some permissions problems here. our backup writes to the DB server, and is enacted by an account that has backup access to DB and write access to server
stsadm -o backup -directory \\servername\share\sharepoint_backup\ -backupmethod full
```

Then to clean up every N days the backups I use [BackupCleanup.vbs](http://pastebin.ca/1543339). Check the comments at the top for testing.

Usage:

```
cscript.exe BackupCleanUp.vbs <Number of Days> \\servername\share\sharepoint_backup\spbrtoc.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has some pretty good tools for that. And a content database backup is pretty useful for most disaster recovery models.